# ReactJS: Unable to get the value from a select dropdown because the value is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown

I just wanted to make a proof of concept that based on the person's search text and the option they select from the dropdown it will redirect them to the search engine of their choice.

```
const options = [
  { value: 'http://www.google.com/search?q=', label: 'Google' },
  { value: 'http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=', label: 'Yahoo' },
  { value: 'https://www.bing.com/search?q=', label: 'Bing' },
  { value: 'https://duckduckgo.com/?q=', label: 'DuckDuckGo' }
]

//const [selection, setSearch] = useState("");


const doSearch = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  var sf=document.searchform;
  var submitto = sf.sengines[sf.sengines.selectedIndex].value + (sf.searchterms.value);
  console.log("log: " + submitto);
  window.location.href = submitto;
  //window.location.replace(submitto)
  return null;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>Search:</p>
        <form name="searchform" onSubmit={doSearch}>
        <Select id="sengines" options={options}/>
        For:
        <input type="text" name='searchTerms'/>
        <input type="submit" name="SearchSubmit" value="Search"></input>
        </form>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I hit search it throws an error saying that the selectedIndex is undefined. Is there a syntax mistake I am making that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was easier to solve than I realized.

```
sf.searchTerms.value
```

Needs to be camel cased

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake might be the line where you're doing

```
var sf=document.searchform;
```

To get a form element by its name, try doing

```
var sf = document.getElementsByName("searchForm")[0];
```

Comment: That isn't where the error get's thrown. It happens on the line after. I through in a little alert to see if it could find the search the way I have it written and it worked.